# How to parse this type of text?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, json, parsing

*Note* : I am new to python, javascript and scraping.

I am scraping a website in python, using beautiful soup and mechanize.
Some of the data is loaded through ajax requests.
I am having trouble in scraping the response.

**Sample Ajax request URL** : http://example.com/getJSData/?file=/data/js/GetData.js&cmd=GETDATA&rc=BGAN

**Sample Response** : d1=[["m11","m12","m13"],["m21","m22","m23"]];d2=[["x11", "x12"],["x21", "x22"],["x31", "x32"]]

Though the whole repsonse is not a proper json object, the values of each of d1 and d2 is a valid JSON object, that I can parse using some json parser in python. But how to parse the whole response ?

The obvious way is to search for all the "=" in the response and extract the json object, and then parse it using json parser.

But I feel there must be a more elegant way of doing this (Parsing the whole response). Can you please guide?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One quick note, I believe you mean `scraping`, not `scrapping`

Comment: How is the response being returned? What type of object? A string?

Comment: The response is in valid Python syntax... I wonder if `ast.parse` would be useful here at all.

Comment: @ZachGates : Response is got using br.open(url).get_data(), where br = mechanize.Browser()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kevin notes, this is close enough to Python that we can leverage the `ast` module (in particular, `ast.parse` and `ast.literal_eval`).  For example:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = '''d1=[["m11","m12","m13"],["m21","m22","m23"]];d2=[["x11", "x12"],["x21", "x22"],["x31", "x32"]]'''
>>> {b.targets[0].id: ast.literal_eval(b.value) for b in ast.parse(s).body}
{'d2': [['x11', 'x12'], ['x21', 'x22'], ['x31', 'x32']], 
 'd1': [['m11', 'm12', 'm13'], ['m21', 'm22', 'm23']]}
```

Comment: One question. Is the output that you have shown a proper json object ? Trying it on jsonlint.com to see correctness suggests otherwise.

Comment: @user1599964: no, the output I've shown is a Python dictionary.  If you want to encode that as json, simply bind it to something (say `d`) and then do `json.dumps(d)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your response in a JSON object like so:

JSON Response :

```
{
    d1:[["m11","m12","m13"],["m21","m22","m23"]],
    d2:[["x11", "x12"],["x21", "x22"],["x31", "x32"]]
};
```

Comment: I think he's receiving the response, not generating it. So he can't easily change the "="s to ":"s without some serious parsing.

Comment: @Kevin : Yeah right. Receiving response. In the answer given, I would have to change '=' -> ':'  as well as ';' -> ','. Direct replacing might break the response though.